# I have set up my HTML to send image uploaded by users to my email as url, how do I add preview to the URL so I won’t have to click the url everytime

Tags: html, image, url, server, preview

I have not written any code yet. I need guidance on what to use to add the preview function to the url in my email so it can show me previews of the images

I tried using FileReader but that only works on the client side not the server side, so I’m completely empty and confused on what to do next

Comment: What do the emails look like right now in code? Are they HTML emails?